# rndc replication slower for ns4

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, rndc

I have 4 dns servers named `ns1`, `ns2`, `ns3` and `ns4`. `ns1` is the master and the rest are the slaves. I also use rndc to manage the replication. What I found is interesting is that when I make any modification to the zone files on `ns1`, `ns2`, `ns3` are propagated immediately, but `ns4` takes longer time to be propagated. So What is the behavior of the replication, does the master only push changes to up to 2 slaves in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem is I didn't register `ns4` at Godaddy as a name server for this domain. After I added `ns4` at Godaddy, the replication to `ns4` becomes realtime.